# After trying this example, feeling confused on the basics of Maps and Set in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, set, javascript-objects

I am trying to apply some examples to better understand the difference of Map and Set and the behaviour of each one seems confusing. Look at the examples and output below

Map example:

```
let nameMap = new Map([
  ['name', 'stack'],
  ['name', 'overflow'],
  ['domain', 'technology']
]);

// iterate over keys (nameMap)
for (let name of nameMap) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(name)); 
}
```

output:

```
["name","overflow"]
["domain","technology"]
```

Set Example:

```
let nameSet = new Set([
  ['name', 'stack'],
  ['name', 'overflow'],
  ['domain', 'technology']
]);

// iterate over keys (nameSet)
for (let name of nameSet) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(name));
}
```

output:

```
["name","stack"]
["name","overflow"]
["domain","technology"]
```

1. My question is why map returns only the second occurence of two similar objects?
2. Set returns all three objects even though first two keys and values being same, while it supposed to delete one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is why map returns only the second occurence of two similar objects?

Because a Map contains a set of key-value pairs. You can only have one value per key. In the constructor, each array is represents `[key, value]`). The second bit of data with the key `'name'` overwrites the first one.

> Set returns all three objects even though first two keys and values being same, while it supposed to delete one of them.

A set stores a set of unique values. Each array (like `['name', 'stack']`) is one value.

Comment: So incase of a map, the **name** of the key is important. While the set looks out for unique **references** (incase of an object) before including an object.Did i understand right?

Comment: The set looks for unique values. References to different but identical arrays are different. Two references to the same array are not. Two identical primitives are not.

Answer (score 0):

Because `Set`s are like arrays - they just store the values in a list. Therefore, the constructor will add all three arrays to the new Set as values. The `Map` constructor is similar to `Object.fromEntries` - the first item in each sub-array is the key, the second the value. You can't store keys in a Set, only values - so the two items have to be exactly the same, and a primitive, to be excluded from the Set.

Answer (score 0):

A `Map` is a container for key-value pairs. In your input, `name` and `domain` will become keys. Since a key can only exist once, the key `name` gets deduplicated.

A `Set` is an array of values which deduplicates the values themselves. Since there aren't any identical values in your input, all are retained.